# Is there a way to generate C# Code from Class Diagrams?

Tags: c#, ide, uml

I am using Visual Studio 2019. I cannot seem to find any option to make UML Class Diagram and generate code from it. The language which I'm working on is C#. If there is a way to do it, kindly tell me which libraries and frameworks are required in Visual Studio. You can also recommend another IDE if it does the job with a little briefing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to install Class Designer component. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-designer/how-to-add-class-diagrams-to-projects?view=vs-2019

After your design you can generate de code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/modeling/generate-code-from-uml-class-diagrams?view=vs-2015

Answer (score 0):

You can generate c# code from diagram with Astah UML, it is totaly free for student or it's a free trial and you can reinstall it as you want.
https://astah.net/products/free-student-license/